# Building .net framework 4.5 project with target framework 1.1 (Backwards compatibility issue)

Tags: .net, backwards-compatibility, target-framework

I am working on a mature project that was initially implemented with .net framework 1.1 .

By the time of progress, most of the modules have been upgraded or rewritten with .net framework 4.0 and 4.5.

Currently there are 3 asp .net web applications of the project.

1. Is running with framework 1.1
2. Is running with framework 4.0
3. Is running with framework 4.5

And I have a Visual Studio project, named as "CommonLibrary", written with framework 4.5

Is it possible to use my CommonLibrary in all projects by building it with proper target framework versions?

Comment: No. Versions 2.0 and above are quite similar and you could tweak a 4.5 project down to 2.0, but the 1.1 framework is too different.

Comment: What are the problems you are having when compiling the sources for 1.1. We can't guess your code...

Comment: Actually there is not a problem, if this case is possible, the project would be more consistent. Because the same business logic is implemented both 1.1 and 4.5 . I want to use CommonLibrary in 1.1 but I can not, because there is not 1.1 option in Target Framework section in project settings in Visual Studio (2013||2012). I am very curious If there is a way to do this.

Comment: What platform are you targetting? So far as I'm aware, there's no platform that supports both 1.1 and 4.5, and 1.1 has fallen out of even extended support by now. I know it's probably not under your control, but you really do need to push for an upgrade to happen.

Comment: Currently I m targeting framework 4.5 . I guess 1.1 is tooooooooo old :(

Comment: Why can't you upgrade your 1.1 project to at least 2.0? What you can do, copy files from CommonLibrary into new 1.1 project and compile.

Comment: I can't upgrade 1.1 because it is dependent to Commerce Server that supports 1.1 only. And 4.5 code can not be compiled at 1.1 project because it has lots of linq, claims identity related codes and newer dependencies that framwrk 1.1 can not understand..